# Replace new line in HTML Textarea with semicolon

Tags: c#, html, sql-server

I have an HTML Textarea and I want to convert it to a single line of string with semicolon as separator.

For example I have a list of employee number in HTML Textarea:

```
-------------
|100000001  |
|100000002  |
|100000003  |
|100000004  |
|100000005  |
|100000006  |
|100000007  |
|100000008  |
|100000009  |
|100000010  |
-------------
```

I want it to be converted into a single line of string and replace new line with semicolon and pass it to a variable.

It should be like this:

```
;100000001;100000002;100000003;100000004;100000005;100000006;100000007;100000008;100000009;100000010
```

How can I achieve that?

Or do you have something else to recommend what to use instead of HTML Textarea where the user can input list of employee numbers and allow pasting values from clipboard.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: replace end of line (`\r\n`, `\n` ) with  `;`

Comment: You wanna do it in SQL or c# ?

Comment: @Krishna C# ...

Comment: @theo: ok guy ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in C#:

```
 var result = yourText.Replace("\r\n", ";").Replace("\r", ";").Replace("\n", ";");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do in sql server then

```
select convert(varchar,EmployeeNumber)+';' from EmployeesTable for xml path('')
```

if you are trying to do in c#, then

```
txtMyTextBox.Text = string.Join(";", txtMyTextBox.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate this in the SQL itself then you could do it like this with the help of `SUBSTRING` and `LEN` function.

```
Create table sample(
data varchar(max)
)

insert into sample
values(10000010),
(10000020),
(10000030),
(10000040),
(10000050),
(10000060),
(10000070),
(10000080)

declare @temp varchar(max)
declare @temp2 varchar(max)
set @temp = ''
select @temp = @temp + data + '; ' from sample

select SUBSTRING(@temp,0,LEN(@temp))
```